# Redirect or forward users to appropriate subdomains based on geo-location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-run

I have an app running on google cloud run in different regions. Each region has a unique subdomain URL. For E.g asia.app.co and us.app.co

Now, we have to redirect/forward users to appropriate subdomains based on geo-location, when the root domain is accessed (app.co)

DNS based routing doesn't work as we have to forward to URLs.

How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to follow: [Serving traffic from multiple regions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/multiple-regions)

and more about how load balancer works on [Setting up a multi-region, content-based external HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https#configuring_the_load_balancing_resources)

Comment: Author of the guide here. As the guide says, you can simply run a single domain name and route users to the nearest Cloud Run region that has the app deployed. That way you don't have to do `asia.app.co` etc.